# C Macro Definition on Command Line vs in Code

Tags: c

Consider the following toy program (call it `Foo.c`), and observe that `#define FOO` is commented out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// #define FOO
int main(){
#if FOO
    printf("Foo\n");
#else
    printf("Bar\n");
#endif
}
```

The compiles fine with the following two command lines.

```
 gcc -o Foo Foo.c
 gcc -DFOO -o Foo Foo.c
```

However, if we uncomment the line `#define FOO`, and compile with `gcc -o Foo Foo.c`, this generates a compiler error.

```
Foo.c:5:8: error: #if with no expression
 #if FOO
        ^
```

1. What is the difference between `-DFOO` on the command line and `#define FOO` in the code?
2. Why does the command line definition work but the inline definition cause a compiler error?

**Note**: I am aware that this behavior can be rectified with `#ifdef` and/or `#define FOO 1`. The purpose of this question is to *request an explanation, not a resolution*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the command line with GCC, `-DFOO` is a shorthand for `-DFOO=1`.  To demonstrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// #define FOO
int main(){
#if FOO
    printf("Foo %d\n", FOO);
#else
    printf("Bar %d\n", FOO);
#endif
}
```

That will now only compile with `-DFOO` (or with an explicit value `-DFOO=-32768`, or with `#define FOO 1` or similar).

```
$ gcc -o md -DFOO md.c && ./md
Foo 1
$
```

This is actually required by the POSIX standard for [`c99`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html)

> `-D  name[=value]`
>   Define name as if by a C-language `#define` directive. If no `=value` is given, a value of 1 shall be used. The `-D` option has lower precedence than the `-U` option. That is, if `name` is used in both a `-U` and a `-D` option, `name` shall be undefined regardless of the order of the options.

So it will work essentially anywhere.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually addresses my question!

Comment: Will accept in a few minutes, but would also appreciate a doc reference for the shorthand, if you have it handy.

Answer (score 2):

Use #ifdef instead of #if to check if a macro is defined. Otherwise, you can change your macro to #define FOO 0 or #define FOO 1 to enable/disable your code.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// #define FOO
int main(){
#ifdef FOO
    printf("Foo\n");
#else
    printf("Bar\n");
#endif
}
```

Comment: My question is not how to fix it. My question is *why* the observed behavior happens.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
#define FOO
```

means that `FOO` is pre-processed as an empty string.
The line `#if FOO` becomes `#if`, which of course is a syntax error, as made clear by the error message “#if with no expression”.

When `-DFOO` is not present on the commandline, `FOO` is not defined to be anything, so the line `#if FOO` is still `#if FOO` after the substitution phase of pre-processing (a symbol such as `FOO` that is not explicitly defined evaluates to `0` inside a `#if` condition). When `-DFOO` is present, it causes `FOO` to be substituted with `1`, again leaving the line `#if FOO` syntactically valid after substitution.

The equivalent `#define` definition to the commandline option `-DFOO` is `#define FOO 1`.

The equivalent commandline option to `#define FOO` is `-DFOO=`

Comment: This gets at half the issue, but does not address the second half, which is why `-DFOO` works correctly.

Comment: @merlin2011 I was busy writing it as you commented. Specifically, I was busy fact-checking with `gcc -C -E test.c`, and I recommend that you use this command if you have other interrogations about pre-processing.

Answer (score 0):

According to 6.10.1p3 of C99 (talking about #if and #elif):

> After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers are replaced with the pp-number 0, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token.

So, `FOO`, when undefined, becomes a literal `0` by this rule, and `#if FOO` doesn't give you an error. However, when you `#define FOO`, it expands into nothing (as you defined it) and you get an error.

GCC's `-DFOO` doesn't exactly behave like you'd expect (like `#define FOO`) — it gives it a default value of `1`. (edit: Apparently this is POSIX mandated…, see Jonathan Leffler's answer.)

Answer (score 0):

When a C program gets compiled, the C compiler passes through your code several times. The first pass through is called the preprocessor expansion stage. `#define` works very much like a word processor's copy and paste. When the compiler comes to this line:

```
#define FOO
```

the compiler keeps like an internal dictionary of names and values. It takes `FOO` (the name) and associates it in the dictionary with whatever text follows it (the value). In this case, you have no value after it, so an empty string is stored as the value.

When the compiler gets to this line:

```
#if FOO
```

The compiler looks for the name `FOO` in its dictionary and it says "hmm do I have a name in my dictionary called `FOO`". If it doesn't, an error occurs. In this case though, there is a `FOO` name in the dictionary and it replaces the name `FOO` with whatever value is associated with it (the empty string). So the line becomes this:

```
#if
```

After the compiler gets done with the preprocessor expansion phase, it runs through your code again, executing preprocessor directives (such as `#if`). When it gets to the expanded `#if` line, its invalid because nothing is following the `#if` and the compiler doesn't know how to handle that.

To make your code valid, there are 2 fixes. One is to define your `FOO` like this:

```
#define FOO 1
```

By doing this, the preprocessor expansion stage would expand the line to look like this:

```
#if 1
```

Since a `1` in C is interpreted as true, it will compile just fine.

The second way to fix it is to change your `#if` to `#ifdef`. `#ifdef` is a preprocessor directive that evaluates to true if `FOO` is defined. What its defined as is irrelevant. It will return true regardless of the value.

Answer (score 0):

**#if** expect an **expression**, and Foo is not an expression.
take a look at this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

in your case, you must use **#ifdef** & **#ifndef**

Comment: Why are you citing a C# reference document? And `FOO` is an “expression” (what you call what `#if` expects), it is an expression that evaluates to 0.

Comment: sorry for that, i was just looking for a clear example, because there exactly the same concept, these two reference from gnu and msdn http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html and this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx